# How to PIVOT a select result as mentioned in the query

Tags: sql, sql-server, pivot, pivot-table

I have query as mentioned below

```
SELECT Project
    ,STATUS
    ,count(*) AS [count]
FROM Defect
GROUP BY Project
    ,STATUS
ORDER BY Project
```

which will return a table like

[image]

I'm trying to PIVOT this result as below

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Convert Rows to columns using 'Pivot' in SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15931607/convert-rows-to-columns-using-pivot-in-sql-server)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try the below way -

```
SELECT * FROM   
(
    SELECT Project,STATUS,count(*) AS cnt FROM Defect GROUP BY Project,STATUS
) t 
PIVOT(
    sum(cnt) 
    FOR STATUS IN (
        [Build Assigned], 
        [Build Delivered], 
        [Closed], 
        [Eng. Build Delivered], 
        [New], 
        [Non-Issue], 
        [Open],[Pending])
) AS pivot_table
```

Comment: Any way to get 0 instead of NULL if the status not present for a project?

Answer (score 1):

would be

```
with base as
(
SELECT Project
    ,STATUS
    ,count(*) AS [count]
FROM Defect
GROUP BY Project
    ,STATUS
)
select *
from base
pivot (
sum([count])
for base.status in ([Build Delivered],[New],[...],[...])
) as x
order by project
;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use aggregated function `sum` with `case` expressions as following

```
select
  project,
  sum(case when status = 'Build Assigned' then count else 0 end) as Build_Assigned,
  sum(case when status = 'Build Delivered' then count else 0 end) as Build_Delivered
from yourTable
group by
  project
```